# Potential Energies of Charges

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential-energy, coulombs-law

Do particles have potential energy because they experience Coulombic forces from other particles? If a particle is placed in a region where there is no charges present around, then is the potential energy zero?

Answer (score 0):

In a word, yes. The important thing to remember here is that **charges do not feel the effects of their own fields.**

Comment: one remark for the special case of an accelerating charge [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham–Lorentz_force)

Answer (score 0):

Charged particles or objects acquire potential energy when work is done on them in order to move them in a region where an electric field is present. The change in potential energy is, then, equal to the opposite of the work done (assuming only electrostatic field is present in the region):
for example if a charge $q = 1\,\, C$ is moved by $1$ m in a region of constant electric field of magnitude $E =1 $ $\frac{V}{m}$ parallel to the displacement, the change in potential energy of the charge is $\Delta U = - W =  q E \Delta x = 1 \,\,J$

As you can see, I made no explicit reference to the presence of *source charges*: what is important is the presence of an **electric field** in the region of interest. Let's say you have a region $\Sigma$ somewhere in the Universe where there are absolutely no charges except for the one you put there (your *test charge*), but an electric field is present. Your particle will then experience a force due to the electric field and, therefore, change its potential energy, even if no other charge is present *inside $\Sigma$*. Of course, since charges are the ultimate sources of every electric field, there will be, in some other region of the Universe, a distribution of charge that creates the electric field in $\Sigma$.

So to summarise the answer, the presence of a distribution of charge *in a given region* is not strictly necessary in order for a charged test particle to change its potential energy; all there needs to be is an electric field in the region. This implies, of course, that a distribution of charge is present *somewhere* to generate the electric field of interest. It just doesn't have to be in the region of interest.

EDIT: Mathematically, what I am saying is that even if the charge in a given region $\Sigma$ is zero, the potential $\phi$ is not necessarily zero: in fact it satisfies the Laplace equation $\nabla ^2 \phi = 0$ that, with appropriate boundary conditions, has an unique solution for the potential in the region of interest.

Comment: It seems to be a little bit nonsense about charge-free space in which an electric field exist. This field could exist only if there are charges.

Comment: @HolgerFiedler  I am not talking about charge-free **space**, I  am talking about a charge-free **region**. As I said in the last paragraph of my answer,  "a distribution of charge is present somewhere. [..] It just doesn't have to be in the region of interest".
Since the question was "if a charge is placed _in a region_ where there is no charge will it have zero potential energy?", the answer is **no** for the reasons I stated above.
If you want, it is like taking a region where the Laplace equation for the potential is verified; the potential in the region is not  zero, even if charge is.

Comment: Ok, understood it.